# SQL, Laravel: When to create a relationship?

Tags: mysql, laravel, relational-database, eloquent

I'm exploring the fields of SQL and relational databases since I'm relatively new to database design and I was wondering about how table/object relationships work. By relationships I mean referencing an id on another table, which is heavily used in frameworks like Laravel with it's ORM Eloquent. In the Documents it's stated how to create relationships, but not WHY and WHEN? What are the benefits or the drawbacks of not doing it?

**So my question; When and why do we need to create relationships between tables?**

**Example:** 
I was practicing on a Laravel Application for our local indoor Football/Soccer Club which uses multiple tables (and what made me confused about the concept). The tables/resources of my app are:

1. Competitions
2. Teams
3. Matches
4. Locations

To clear up: There are 7 competitions of 12 teams (so total 84 teams total) who play matches at 3 indoor courts. The matches of every competition are not tied to 1 court, so competition 2B has matches at court 1 and 2 par example.

The target of my app is to show the program/schedule, fixtures and rankings of the different competitions. I want to use relationships so I can retrieve all matches played at court 1 or all matches of competition 2A.

I presumed the relations to be like this:

```
1. Competitions -> hasMany Teams,  | Teams   -> belongTo Competition
2. Competitions -> hasMany Matches | Matches -> belongTo Competition
3. Location     -> hasMany Matches | Matches -> belongTo Location
4. Matches      -> hasMany Teams   | Teams   -> HaveMany Teams
```

I created the migrations and the models but I bump into error after error. For example every match has two teams, how to specify this relation? And matches, they belong to a competition and as well to a Location so I can query both locations with all their matches and competitions with all their matches.

Is this all even possible or does evert table can only have one parent/child relation?

Maybe someone has some good resources on this matter for beginner to novice for me to learn and grasp the basics of this matter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ORM helps you start quickly. It is not enough for any bigger app, but leveraging its features lets you focus on important things, while not having to reinventing the wheel for basic stuff. Your relations can be setup with a few lines of code for each model and they will work - this is your **why**. **When**? I would say, whenever you don't need anything more robust. Then you create custom methods, or replace Eloquent with, say, Doctrine. And for last question - you can define any number of relations on you models.  Show your code if you want assist with the errors.

Comment: So I can give a model multiple parents (belongsTo) relations? How do I save a child model which has two parents? The only thing in the docs I can find is how to save a model with one relationship.

Comment: Sure you can. Describe your case, then I can give you some advice.

Comment: Let's say I want to add seasons. Every year the application admin adds a new season, but without having to add the teams once again or create new competitions. He only should need to fill in all the matches. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Another Example: I have a matches table which has two teams (home and away). How do I specify a relation in a way that if I query the Matches table the teams get loaded?

Comment: 1 You have a table with teams, so no need to fill it again. However consider changes that can be made in the future but shouldn't affect archive seasons. 2 A `match`/`fixture` is simply link between 2 teams with given date and location (and more features, depending on your needs), so treat it as a pivot table. You can create a model for it, then define relations: `homeTeam`, `awayTeam` both referencing `teams` table, but using different foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm going to try to give you a quick answer. 
Basically you create relationships between your models because they are part of their definitions.

WHY ? Because it helps in many cases.

If we take your first relationShip :

```
 1. Competitions -> hasMany Teams,  | Teams   -> belongTo Competition
```

Defining that relationship will ease the following operations :

- Define the teams which are part of a competition.

> $competition->teams()->save($newTeam);

- Retrieve the teams which are part of a competition.

> $teams = $competition->teams();

- Retrieve the competitions which are played by a certain team.

> $competitions = $team->competitions();

as those kinds of operations are very common Eloquent ORM allows you to use his simple and efficient syntax instead of writing sometimes complex SQL requests.

WHEN ? Anytime those kinds of relations exists between your models, declare them, always.